# Convert Unicode Output of Tuple into string Python

Tags: python, for-loop, unicode, tuples

I have the following response I am getting when I for loop through the following:

```
for col in ids:

        print (format(col)),
    print ("\n")
    print type(ids[0])
```

I have a tuple that has element of different type: unicode, and int.

```
(u'0021401225', u'0021401203', u'0021401167', u'0021401148', u'0021401124', u'0021401092', u'0021401078', u'0021401066', u'0021401037', u'0021401023', u'0021401005', u'0021400995', u'0021400985', u'0021400964', u'0021400948', u'0021400924', u'0021400915', u'0021400900', u'0021400891', u'0021400854', u'0021400839', u'0021400821', u'0021400809', u'0021400800', u'0021400796', u'0021400766', u'0021400747', u'0021400743', u'0021400718', u'0021400711', u'0021400700', u'0021400681', u'0021400676', u'0021400658', u'0021400643', u'0021400626', u'0021400620', u'0021400599', u'0021400586', u'0021400570', u'0021400561', u'0021400547', u'0021400523', u'0021400503', u'0021400484', u'0021400479', u'0021400466', u'0021400429', u'0021400416', u'0021400401', u'0021400386', u'0021400370', u'0021400355', u'0021400336', u'0021400326', u'0021400308', u'0021400303', u'0021400281', u'0021400273', u'0021400253', u'0021400238', u'0021400211', u'0021400199', u'0021400186', u'0021400179', u'0021400159', u'0021400147', u'0021400133', u'0021400125', u'0021400098', u'0021400081', u'0021400066', u'0021400055', u'0021400022', u'0021400018')
```

I'm trying to store these values without the

> u'

Because I can key off of these id's later in my program. But I just want to store them as integers which might look like the below:

> [('0021401225','0021401203', '0021401167', '0021401148','0021401124',
>   '0021401092', '0021401078', '0021401066', '0021401037', '0021401023')]

I would like to for-loop through them.

Comment: The `u` prefix indicates you have an unicode character string, rather than a byte string. Both types will work equally well as a key. You can convert them to actual integers using the answer below but by using `int` instead of `str`.

Comment: don't use `repr(some_tuple)` as your storage format. You could use `json` instead: `json.dumps(some_tuple)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lt = (u'0021401225', u'0021401203', u'0021401167', u'0021401148', u'0021401124', u'0021401092', u'0021401078', u'0021401066', u'0021401037', u'0021401023', u'0021401005', u'0021400995', u'0021400985', u'0021400964', u'0021400948', u'0021400924', u'0021400915', u'0021400900', u'0021400891', u'0021400854', u'0021400839', u'0021400821', u'0021400809', u'0021400800', u'0021400796', u'0021400766', u'0021400747', u'0021400743', u'0021400718', u'0021400711', u'0021400700', u'0021400681', u'0021400676', u'0021400658', u'0021400643', u'0021400626', u'0021400620', u'0021400599', u'0021400586', u'0021400570', u'0021400561', u'0021400547', u'0021400523', u'0021400503', u'0021400484', u'0021400479', u'0021400466', u'0021400429', u'0021400416', u'0021400401', u'0021400386', u'0021400370', u'0021400355', u'0021400336', u'0021400326', u'0021400308', u'0021400303', u'0021400281', u'0021400273', u'0021400253', u'0021400238', u'0021400211', u'0021400199', u'0021400186', u'0021400179', u'0021400159', u'0021400147', u'0021400133', u'0021400125', u'0021400098', u'0021400081', u'0021400066', u'0021400055', u'0021400022', u'0021400018')

lt = list(map(str,lt) )

print(lt)

['0021401225', '0021401203', '0021401167', '0021401148', '0021401124', '0021401092', '0021401078', '0021401066', '0021401037', '0021401023', '0021401005', '0021400995', '0021400985', '0021400964', '0021400948', '0021400924', '0021400915', '0021400900', '0021400891', '0021400854', '0021400839', '0021400821', '0021400809', '0021400800', '0021400796', '0021400766', '0021400747', '0021400743', '0021400718', '0021400711', '0021400700', '0021400681', '0021400676', '0021400658', '0021400643', '0021400626', '0021400620', '0021400599', '0021400586', '0021400570', '0021400561', '0021400547', '0021400523', '0021400503', '0021400484', '0021400479', '0021400466', '0021400429', '0021400416', '0021400401', '0021400386', '0021400370', '0021400355', '0021400336', '0021400326', '0021400308', '0021400303', '0021400281', '0021400273', '0021400253', '0021400238', '0021400211', '0021400199', '0021400186', '0021400179', '0021400159', '0021400147', '0021400133', '0021400125', '0021400098', '0021400081', '0021400066', '0021400055', '0021400022', '0021400018']
```

Comment: It works! Thank you! So when I print lt, it will be formatted as a list?